# Windows 10 uwp - Entity Core Sqlite : Include query error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sqlite, uwp

In a Windows 10 UWP application, I'm using a local sqlite data base with Entity Framework Core 1.1 and it's working fine for now except for this :

I'm trying to use a simple linq query to include a related object to my user object. I tested a few queries, but lambdas with include method and a select restriction are not working.

Code sample :

```
public async Task<IUser> GetAsync(Guid id)
{
    // Working, but useless
    var user = await this.DbSet.Include(u => u.ProfileNavigation).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // Returns null
    var user1 = await this.DbSet.Include(u => u.ProfileNavigation).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.IdGuid == id);

    // Returns null
    var user2 = await this.DbSet.Where(u => u.IdGuid == id).Include(u => u.ProfileNavigation).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // Returns null linked object
    User user3 = await this.DbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.IdGuid == id);
    await this.Context.Entry(user3).Reference(p => p.ProfileNavigation).LoadAsync();

    // Result valid but painfull
    User res = await (from u in this.DbSet
                      join p in this.Context.Set<Profile>() on u.ProfileGuid equals p.IdGuid
                      where u.IdGuid == id
                      select new User
                      {
                          Id = u.Id,
                          ProfileId = u.ProfileId,
                          ManagerUserId = u.ManagerUserId,
                          RegionId = u.RegionId,
                          Number = u.Number,
                          Password = u.Password,
                          FirstName = u.FirstName,
                          LastName = u.LastName,
                          Email = u.Email,
                          HideOnBoardAppConstr = u.HideOnBoardAppConstr,
                          ModifiedByUserId = u.ModifiedByUserId,
                          ProfileNavigation = p
                      }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return res;
}
```

Does anyone had this issue and solved it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official document about [create Database by the Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started).

> In this walkthrough, you will build a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application that performs basic data access against a local SQLite database using Entity Framework.

You should be able to check if the BloggingContext class that includes the `Blog` and `Post` classes as the sample.

There is a also document for [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is achieved by use of the Include method. For example, the queries below will load blogs and all the posts related to each blog.

For example:

The BloggingContext class:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blogging.db");
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

The include query code:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs1 = db.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is partially solved by using a data base context instance for each request. The problem was linked to the depedency injection of the context (I tried with SimpleIoc and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection), but it's still confusing to me.

Any comments are welcome.